# Shiny dashboard checkbox input based on the df

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to build a Shiny dashboard that includes a checkbox that allows to select years. Here is the simple code that gives me that.

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(verbatimTextOutput("value")),
      
      box(
       
          checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = "Year", 
                           choices = list("2019" = 2019, "2020" = 2020),
                           selected = 1)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$checkGroup })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I want is to read the values for the checkbox from a dataframe instead of specifying them manually as above. For example, say I have a follwing df:

```
geo <- data.frame("year" = c(2018, 2019, 2020), "geo" = c("Europe", "Asia", "America"), "sales" = c(100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500))
```

My checkbox should now include 2018, 2019 and 2020, but if I update the df with the data for 2021 as well, I want it to automatically appear in the checkbox. So, in other words, I want to use distinct values of column year as possible choices. I've tried to use distnct from tidyverse in the following way but with no success:

```
checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = "Year", 
                   choices = as.list(distinct(geo,year)),
                   selected = 1)
```

Any ideaas?

Best regards

Comment: Maybe you just want `unique(geo$year)` for `choices`? Using `distinct(geo, year)` will give you a 1-column data frame with `year` as the column (selecting unique rows based on year) - so `distinct(geo, year)$year` would provide the same choices in this case I believe...

Comment: @Ben unique(geo$year) works fine. Thanks a lot!